# Local rotation in specific implementation openGL and LWJGL

Tags: java, opengl, rotation, local, lwjgl

I am also fiddling with the global/local rotation problem and I cannnot put my finger on it. I used [a lwjgl book](https://lwjglgamedev.gitbooks.io/3d-game-development-with-lwjgl/) for the implementation of my game, using openGL and LWJGL. I am using the JOML lib for vectors and matrices.

The modelview matrix construction is below. By the book, this is originally without local rotations, I added them myself. The idea is that each object has a global and local rotation. Those rotations get individually calculated and then are multiplied left/right side with the modelview matrix.

```
public Matrix4f getModelViewMatrix(Object obj, Matrix4f viewMatrix) {
    Vector3f rotation = obj.getRot();
    Vector3f localRot = obj.getLocalRot();

    Matrix4f localRotMat = new Matrix4f().identity();
    Matrix4f worldRotMat = new Matrix4f().identity();

    localRotMat.rotateLocalX((float)Math.toRadians(localRot.x)).
                rotateLocalY((float)Math.toRadians(localRot.y)).
                rotateLocalZ((float)Math.toRadians(localRot.z));

    worldRotMat.rotateX((float)Math.toRadians(-rotation.x)).
                rotateY((float)Math.toRadians(-rotation.y)).
                rotateZ((float)Math.toRadians(-rotation.z));

    modelViewMatrix.identity().translate(obj.getPos());

    modelViewMatrix.mulLocal(localRotMat);
    modelViewMatrix.mul(worldRotMat);

    modelViewMatrix.scale(obj.getScale());
    Matrix4f viewCurr = new Matrix4f(viewMatrix);
    return viewCurr.mul(modelViewMatrix);
}
```

This still results in local rotations around the 'wrong' axes. I've seen implementations using quaternions and read about gimbal lock and the like, but either the answers are very specific or too general for me. Furthermore, it would be great if I wouldn't need to use a quaternions implementation, as I would have to refactor a lot of code possibly.

Relevant code for the object class:

```
// Object class
private final Vector3f rot;

private final Vector3f localRot;

public Object() {
    pos = new Vector3f(0, 0, 0);
    scale = 1;
    rot = new Vector3f(0, 0, 0);
    localRot = new Vector3f(0, 0, 0);
}

// getters and setters for above
```

Can somebody explain what is wrong about the calculation of the rotations for the modelview matrix?

EDIT:
I can rewrite the code like below, which is a bit more in line with the hints from @GeestWagen. However, the 'local rotation' of my object is still displayed as global, so it indeed seems like it is applied 'the same' rotation twice. However, now I am stuck, because I cant find more documentation on these functions (rotateLocal/rotate).

```
modelViewMatrix.identity().translate(obj.getPos()).
                rotateLocalX((float)Math.toRadians(-localRot.x)).
                rotateLocalY((float)Math.toRadians(-localRot.y)).
                rotateLocalZ((float)Math.toRadians(-localRot.z)).
                rotateX((float)Math.toRadians(-rotation.x)).
                rotateY((float)Math.toRadians(-rotation.y)).
                rotateZ((float)Math.toRadians(-rotation.z)).
                scale(obj.getScale());
```

Comment: i think you are transforming the local position twice. I'm not really a expert so my advice is to go checkout [the documentation](https://github.com/JOML-CI/JOML) also read [this page](https://github.com/JOML-CI/JOML/wiki/Anti-Patterns-and-Best-Practices) on anti-patterns thoroughly

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I finally fixed it. It resulted in me doing a bunch more research. What I came up with was the following:

```
Vector3f rotation = obj.getRot();
Vector3f localRot = obj.getLocalRot();

Quaternionf rotationQ = new Quaternionf().
        rotateAxis((float)Math.toRadians(-localRot.z), new Vector3f(0f, 0f, 1f)).
        rotateAxis((float)Math.toRadians(-localRot.y), new Vector3f(0f, 1f, 0f)).
        rotateAxis((float)Math.toRadians(-localRot.x), new Vector3f(1f, 0f, 0f)).
    premul(new Quaternionf().
        rotateX((float)Math.toRadians(-rotation.x)).
        rotateY((float)Math.toRadians(-rotation.y)).
        rotateZ((float)Math.toRadians(-rotation.z))
    );

modelViewMatrix.identity().
    translate(obj.getPos()).
    rotate(rotationQ).
    scale(obj.getScale());
```

This is inspired by among others [this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/understanding-rotations-in-local-and-world-space-quaternions.153330/) and [this](https://answers.unity.com/questions/906747/combining-2-rotations-global-and-local.html). What confused me a lot was the lack of hits on doing local **and** global rotations. Most stuff I was able to find was *either*. This creates a quaternion and sets the x, y, and z axes to the local rotation of the object. Then it *pre-multiplies* by a quaternion which axes are set to the global rotation of the object. Then this resulting quaternion is used for the modelView matrix.

Thus, for combining local and global rotations, a quaternion seems to be necessary. I thought it was used to make sure the axes do not change *in* a local/global rotation, but they should also be used when combining both.

Comment: "Thus, for combining local and global rotations, a quaternion seems to be necessary." Nope. Using quaternions for rotations is exactly as powerful as using matrices.